# WhatsApp Api: как получить ссылку приглашения в группу чата?

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

Есть очень хорошая библиотека для работы с WhatsApp Api:
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

В ней есть требуемые методы для работы с группой чата (создание группы, добавление/удаление участников):
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation#creating-a-group

Но, в ней не предусмотрена возможность получить ссылку приглашения в группу чата.
Ссылки на приглашение в группу чата такого вида: https://chat.whatsapp.com/oMXlKBIlJc7CxQWiBr6VA7

Подскажите, как можно получить ссылку приглашения в группу чата через WhatsApp Api?

В самом приложении ссылку приглашения в группу чата можно получить следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]